# What does the term "template" mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am learning Rails 5.0, via a tutorial. Learning how to generate view templates, but the term "template" is never explicitly defined. I've searched in the Rails docs, and they seem to mention the word a lot, but also never really define it explicitly.

I know that views are the HTML, CSS associated with what the user sees. But was wondering what is a template and how is it different than a standard webpage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an authoritative answer. But this is really rather simple. RoR lets you generate content dynamically. This means, with one template, you could generate different content (html pages). The final html page generated and served by the server is the webpage endusers see. For example, you could have a template show.html.erb with the following line:

```
<h> Product <%=@product.name%> </h>
```

From this template, different webpages for each different @product can be generated with that @product's name, depending on the @product variable, which is provided by the controller.

So templates allow you to dynamically generate content and render them as different html webpages.

Comment: Ok so standard webpage = static content, templates = dynamic content, and that's really the only difference?

Comment: I've just edited my answer from 'generate dynamic content' to 'dynamically generate content'. I think this is more appropriate. Html pages can have dynamic content, e.g. by using javascript. But RoR can dynamically generate different html pages from the same template through its controller action.